# xml validation warnings while installing oracle order fusion demo

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am currently working on Oracle Adf and currently trying to install Oracle fusion demo application opening infrastructure.jws and running buildAll on build.xml giving me following warnings and error

```
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:21 PM oracle.security.jps.util.JpsUtil disableAudit
INFO: JpsUtil: isAuditDisabled set to true
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:22 PM oracle.security.jps.util.JpsUtil disableAudit
INFO: JpsUtil: isAuditDisabled set to true
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:25 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:25 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'propertySets' is not complete. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd":propertySet}' is expected. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:25 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:25 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'propertySets' is not complete. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd":propertySet}' is expected. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:26 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:26 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'propertySets' is not complete. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd":propertySet}' is expected. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:26 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:26 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'propertySets' is not complete. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd":propertySet}' is expected. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:26 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.
Oct 3, 2013 5:25:27 PM oracle.security.jps.internal.common.util.StrictValidationEventHandler handleEvent
WARNING: Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd' must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.
```

Following errors are appearing

```
Buildfile: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo\Infrastructure\Ant\build.xml

init:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo\Infrastructure\Ant\classes

setProperties:

createDatabase:

refreshSchema:

BUILD FAILED
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo\Infrastructure\Ant\build.xml:51: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo\Infrastructure\DBSchema\build.xml:100: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo\Infrastructure\DBSchema\build.xml:63: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo\Infrastructure\DBSchema\build.xml:28: C:\Oracle2\Middleware\jdeveloper\wlserver_10.3\server\lib not found.

Total time: 4 seconds
```

The above are the warnings and errors can anyone please help me with this.Thank You.

Regards,
Furqan Ahmed.

Comment: Ensure your weblogic server files are located in C:\Oracle2\Middleware\jdeveloper\wlserver_10.3\server\lib

Mine are located in C:\Oracle2\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib

Answer (score 1):

try by changing the jdeveloper home to

jdeveloper.home=C:/Oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper

it has worked for me

Answer (score 1):

## Base Directory for library lookup

```
jdeveloper.home=C:/oracle/Middleware/jdeveloper
```

Please see that I use `/` instead of your `\` you use. I tested the scripts an they work if you set the properties to the correct values.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2325005?start=0&tstart=0